AMD RX550 - Only one monitor working at a time on Kubuntu 24.04 (switched from NVIDIA)
Issue Description:
After switching from NVIDIA to AMD graphics card (RX550), I can only get one monitor working at a time. When trying to enable both monitors in KDE's "Display Configuration":

I can enable both monitors in the settings
The settings don't persist after closing the configuration window
Second HDMI monitor remains black (while powered on)
When reopening display settings, the second monitor shows as disabled again

System Information:

OS: Kubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)
Kernel: 6.8.0-47-generic
DE: KDE Plasma 5.27.11
GPU: AMD Lexa PRO [Radeon 540/540X/550/550X / RX 540X/550/550X]
Driver: amdgpu v6.8.5
Display server: Wayland with Xwayland 23.2.6
Compositor: kwin_wayland

What I've done:

Removed all NVIDIA drivers and software
Installed amdgpu drivers

Current monitor setup:

Primary monitor connected via DisplayPort: 5120x1440 @ 119.95Hz
Secondary monitor connected via HDMI (currently not working)

Relevant configuration and logs:

Graphics Information
glxinfo -B
name of display: :1
display: :1  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: AMD (0x1002)
    Device: Radeon RX550/550 Series (radeonsi, polaris12, LLVM 18.1.7, DRM 3.58, 6.8.0-47-generic) (0x699f)
    Version: 24.2.0
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 4096MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
Memory info (GL_ATI_meminfo):
    VBO free memory - total: 2171 MB, largest block: 2171 MB
    VBO free aux. memory - total: 31981 MB, largest block: 31981 MB
    Texture free memory - total: 2171 MB, largest block: 2171 MB
    Texture free aux. memory - total: 31981 MB, largest block: 31981 MB
    Renderbuffer free memory - total: 2171 MB, largest block: 2171 MB
    Renderbuffer free aux. memory - total: 31981 MB, largest block: 31981 MB
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
    Dedicated video memory: 4096 MB
    Total available memory: 36216 MB
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 2171 MB
OpenGL vendor string: AMD
OpenGL renderer string: Radeon RX550/550 Series (radeonsi, polaris12, LLVM 18.1.7, DRM 3.58, 6.8.0-47-generic)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 24.2.0-devel
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.2.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 24.2.0-devel
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20



Display Configuration
xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 8960 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-1 connected primary 5120x1440+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1190mm x 340mm
5120x1440    119.95*+
1920x1440    119.91
[...]



AMD GPU Kernel Modules
amdgpu               19636224  51
amddrm_ttm_helper      12288  1 amdgpu
[...]


Detailed System Information (inxi -SGayz)
lsmod | grep amdgpu
System:
  Kernel: 6.8.0-47-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 13.2.0
    clocksource: tsc avail: hpet,acpi_pm
    parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic
    root=UUID=3da2ea68-fb58-4d04-828e-3280055fbe94 ro nouveau.blacklist=1
    acpi_rev_override=1 acpi_osi=Linux nouveau.modeset=0 pcie_aspm=force
    drm.vblankoffdelay=1 scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1 nouveau.runpm=0
    mem_sleep_default=deep quiet splash vt.handoff=7
  Desktop: KDE Plasma v: 5.27.11 tk: Qt v: 5.15.13 info: frameworks
    v: 5.115.0 wm: kwin_wayland vt: 1 dm: SDDM Distro: Kubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
    (Noble Numbat) base: Ubuntu
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Lexa PRO [Radeon 540/540X/550/550X / RX 540X/550/550X]
    driver: amdgpu v: 6.8.5 arch: GCN-4 code: Arctic Islands process: GF 14nm
    built: 2016-20 pcie: gen: 3 speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 8 ports: active: DP-1
    off: HDMI-A-1 empty: DVI-D-1 bus-ID: 0a:00.0 chip-ID: 1002:699f
    class-ID: 0300 temp: 43.0 C
  Device-2: Logitech C920 PRO HD Webcam driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
    type: USB rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 mode: 2.0 bus-ID: 3-6.3:7
    chip-ID: 046d:08e5 class-ID: 0102 serial: <filter>
  Display: wayland server: X.org v: 1.21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6
    compositor: kwin_wayland driver: N/A display-ID: 0
  Monitor-1: DP-1 res: 5120x1440 size: N/A modes: N/A
  API: EGL v: 1.5 hw: drv: amd radeonsi platforms: device: 0 drv: radeonsi
    device: 1 drv: swrast surfaceless: drv: radeonsi wayland: drv: radeonsi x11:
    drv: radeonsi inactive: gbm
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: amd mesa v: 24.2.0-devel
    glx-v: 1.4 direct-render: yes renderer: Radeon RX550/550 Series (radeonsi
    polaris12 LLVM 18.1.7 DRM 3.58 6.8.0-47-generic) device-ID: 1002:699f
    memory: 3.91 GiB unified: no display-ID: :1.0
  API: Vulkan v: 1.3.275 layers: 7 device: 0 type: discrete-gpu name: Radeon
    RX550/550 Series (RADV POLARIS12) driver: N/A device-ID: 1002:699f
    surfaces: xcb,xlib,wayland device: 1 type: cpu name: llvmpipe (LLVM 17.0.6
    256 bits) driver: N/A device-ID: 10005:0000 surfaces: xcb,xlib,wayland

Additional Notes:

Boot parameters in use: nouveau.blacklist=1 acpi_rev_override=1 acpi_osi=Linux nouveau.modeset=0 pcie_aspm=force drm.vblankoffdelay=1 scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1 nouveau.runpm=0 mem_sleep_default=deep

Question:

How can I get both monitors working simultaneously?
Are there any specific configurations needed for AMD RX550 multi-monitor setup on Kubuntu 24.04?

